# differences in behavior between iterators and indices when moving through vectors

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

When moving through a vector (eg to write it to the console), using the following code, I found some strange behavior:

```
int a;
cin >> a;
vector<int> b(a);
srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
for (int i = 0; i< b.size(); i++)
{
    b[i] = i;
    cout << i << endl;
}




random_shuffle(b.begin(), b.end());

for(iter = b.begin(); iter != b.end(); iter++)
{
    cout << *iter << endl;
}

for (int i = 0; i< b.size(); i++)
{
    b[i] = i;
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

Random shuffle should shuffle all the elements. However, the first cout loop spits out the expected random order, while the second, using the indices, spits out the numbers in exactly the order they were in before the random shuffle. Why is this?

Comment: if your compiler supports C++11 use `std::shuffle` not `std::random_shuffle`.

Comment: I hope you know what the second loop is doing...

Comment: @awesomeyi pointed out what i did wrong - first loop does what it should, last loop is complete garbage. im trying to close the question to hide my eternal shame but it wont let me yet

Comment: Is there a "doh!" tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second loop:

```
b[i] = i;
```

Reassigns `b[i]` to `i` and prints out `i`. You probably want to print out `b[i]`.
Ex:

```
cout << b[i] << endl;
```

Comment: and also change to `cout << b[i] << endl;`